# Excel VBA insert row in a table produces error 1004 when other sheets are protected

Tags: excel, vba

I have an unprotected sheet (MySheet) with a table (MyTable) filled with 10 rows. I'm using the following code to insert a row with some string to the end of the table:

```
Sub AddRowToMyTable()

    Dim the_sheet As Worksheet
    Dim table_list_object As ListObject
    Dim table_object_row As ListRow

    Set the_sheet = Sheets("MySheet")
    Set table_list_object = the_sheet.ListObjects("MyTable")
    Set table_object_row = table_list_object.ListRows.Add

    table_object_row.Range(1, 1).Value = "some string"

End Sub
```

I have more than one sheet in this particular workbook. If other sheets are unprotected, no errors occur, but if just one of the other sheets is protected, I get an error 1004: “Application-defined or Object-defined” when I'm trying to add 11th row. Adding 12th, 13th and further rows work again without an error.

What am my missing?

Comment: It's seems to work even when one of the sheets is protected

Comment: You have the workbook, so you're the only one who can check what links this sheet to other sheets and thereby possibly causes the problem. The list is long: events on sheets (on click, on change, etc.), linked cells, references, named ranges, not sure if there is more.

Comment: ok, tried in a new workbook and it really seems fine also with protected sheets. Will try to eliminate all other things, that may be causing the problem. tnx you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it. On protected sheet I had formulas with what appeared to be wrong references to MyTable data. Instead of referencing the data with 'MySheet'!$A$2:$A$10, one should use MyTable[FirstColumnTitle].